# Which app in Play Store shall I use for app2sd and how shall I use it?

Tags: internal-storage, storage, app2sd

I am learning info from https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info, which says too options for moving apps from internal storage to removable SD card.

My Android 4.4.2 is not rooted, so I guess my Android system itself isn't able to move app to SD card.

According to https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info, which app in Play Store shall I use for my Android 4.4.2? Is Link2SD a good one for mine? I was wondering how to use it? I selected some apps (by starring them), but I don't know what to do next.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: this kind of apps require root access (or at least a mount script, for which you need a root access)

Comment: Is there an app which doesn't require root access? What is my option now for the problem of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228892/how-can-i-increase-storage-space

Comment: root with Kingroot, install SuperSU and delete Kingroot manually. i recommend to make a file list of /system before, that way you know where Kingroot have placed hidden files

Comment: To avoid the kingbloat: shouldn't [Towelroot](https://towelroot.com/) work on Kitkat devices?

Comment: Don't use any app. Bind mount directories (like `/data/data` or `/data/media`) manually by putting an `init.d` script.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Could you be specific?